# How to disable vim strikethrough in vimrc

Tags: vim

Its been like forever, I really dont know how to disable this striketrough in my vim.

Currently I'm using gvim in my ubuntu. Probably there is something wrong with my vimrc setting.

Tried google many months already could not find any solution. Please help

[image]

Below is my vimrc

```
set nocompatible              " be iMproved, required
filetype off                  " required


" set the runtime path to include Vundle and initialize
set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim
call vundle#begin()
" alternatively, pass a path where Vundle should install plugins
"call vundle#begin('~/some/path/here')

" let Vundle manage Vundle, required
Plugin 'VundleVim/Vundle.vim'
Plugin 'scrooloose/nerdtree'
Plugin 'ctrlpvim/ctrlp.vim'
Plugin 'tpope/vim-vinegar'
Plugin 'jistr/vim-nerdtree-tabs'
Plugin 'scrooloose/syntastic'
Plugin 'flazz/vim-colorschemes'
Plugin 'chrisbra/Recover.vim'
Plugin 'MarcWeber/vim-addon-mw-utils'
Plugin 'tomtom/tlib_vim'
Plugin 'garbas/vim-snipmate'
Plugin 'honza/vim-snippets'
Plugin 'posva/vim-vue'


call vundle#end()            " required
filetype plugin indent on    " required
" To ignore plugin indent changes, instead use:
"filetype plugin on
"
" Brief help
" :PluginList       - lists configured plugins
" :PluginInstall    - installs plugins; append `!` to update or just :PluginUpdate
" :PluginSearch foo - searches for foo; append `!` to refresh local cache
" :PluginClean      - confirms removal of unused plugins; append `!` to auto-approve removal
"
" see :h vundle for more details or wiki for FAQ
" Put your non-Plugin stuff after this line

"let base16colorspace=256 " Access colors present in 256 colorspace
"set t_Co=256 " 256 color mode
"set background=dark
"colorscheme base16-ocean

let g:ctrlp_max_files=0
let g:ctrlp_max_depth=40

" Store temporary files in a central spot
let vimtmp = $HOME . '/.tmp/' . getpid()
silent! call mkdir(vimtmp, "p", 0700)
let &backupdir=vimtmp
let &directory=vimtmp


syntax on
syntax enable
"colorscheme Monokai
"colorscheme zenburn
"colorscheme gruvbox 
"colorscheme lucius
colorscheme Monokai 
"colorscheme getafe
"colorscheme CandyPaper
"colorscheme tomorrow-night-eighties
map <C-n> :NERDTreeToggle<CR>
let NERDTreeShowHidden=1
set guitablabel=%N:%M%t " Show tab numbers
set hlsearch
"set incsearch
set relativenumber
set laststatus=2
set linespace=15
set clipboard=unnamedplus
set guifont=Monospace\ 12

filetype plugin indent on
" show existing tab with 4 spaces width
set tabstop=4
" when indenting with '>', use 4 spaces width
set shiftwidth=4
" On pressing tab, insert 4 spaces
set expandtab

map <C-F12> :tabe ~/.vimrc<CR>
map <C-F11> :tab sp<CR>:e ~/.vim/snippets/php.snippets<CR>
map <C-F10> :tab sp<CR>:e sudo /etc/hosts<CR>
map <C-F9> :tab sp<CR>:e ~/Code/AdminLTE-2.3.0/pages/UI/icons.html<CR>
```

Comment: It would probably help if you could show us the contents of your `.vimrc`.

Comment: Does it help if you disable the color scheme, or switch to a different font?

Comment: I tried many colorshcheme... all of them still show the same. Strikethrough

Comment: Tried disabling plugins one by one to figure out which one is causing it?

Answer (score 0):

After playing around changing colorscheme to gruvbox and add this line,

```
let html_no_rendering=1
```

suddenly the strikethrough all disappear. But the colorscheme I need to chose is not the one I want. Anyway if somebody can advise. Please comment.

```
set nocompatible              " be iMproved, required
filetype off                  " required


" set the runtime path to include Vundle and initialize
set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim
call vundle#begin()
" alternatively, pass a path where Vundle should install plugins
"call vundle#begin('~/some/path/here')

" let Vundle manage Vundle, required
Plugin 'VundleVim/Vundle.vim'
Plugin 'scrooloose/nerdtree'
Plugin 'ctrlpvim/ctrlp.vim'
Plugin 'tpope/vim-vinegar'
Plugin 'jistr/vim-nerdtree-tabs'
Plugin 'scrooloose/syntastic'
Plugin 'flazz/vim-colorschemes'
Plugin 'chrisbra/Recover.vim'
Plugin 'MarcWeber/vim-addon-mw-utils'
Plugin 'tomtom/tlib_vim'
Plugin 'garbas/vim-snipmate'
Plugin 'honza/vim-snippets'
Plugin 'posva/vim-vue'


call vundle#end()            " required
filetype plugin indent on    " required
" To ignore plugin indent changes, instead use:
"filetype plugin on
"
" Brief help
" :PluginList       - lists configured plugins
" :PluginInstall    - installs plugins; append `!` to update or just :PluginUpdate
" :PluginSearch foo - searches for foo; append `!` to refresh local cache
" :PluginClean      - confirms removal of unused plugins; append `!` to auto-approve removal
"
" see :h vundle for more details or wiki for FAQ
" Put your non-Plugin stuff after this line

"let base16colorspace=256 " Access colors present in 256 colorspace
"set t_Co=256 " 256 color mode
"set background=dark
"colorscheme base16-ocean

let g:ctrlp_max_files=0
let g:ctrlp_max_depth=40

" Store temporary files in a central spot
let vimtmp = $HOME . '/.tmp/' . getpid()
silent! call mkdir(vimtmp, "p", 0700)
let &backupdir=vimtmp
let &directory=vimtmp


syntax on
syntax enable
"colorscheme Monokai
"colorscheme zenburn
"colorscheme gruvbox 
"colorscheme lucius
colorscheme gruvbox
"colorscheme getafe
"colorscheme CandyPaper
"colorscheme tomorrow-night-eighties
map <C-n> :NERDTreeToggle<CR>
let NERDTreeShowHidden=1
set guitablabel=%N:%M%t " Show tab numbers
set hlsearch
"set incsearch
set relativenumber
set laststatus=2
set linespace=15
set clipboard=unnamedplus
set guifont=Monospace\ 12

filetype plugin indent on
" show existing tab with 4 spaces width
set tabstop=4
" when indenting with '>', use 4 spaces width
set shiftwidth=4
" On pressing tab, insert 4 spaces
set expandtab
let html_no_rendering=1
map <C-F12> :tabe ~/.vimrc<CR>
map <C-F11> :tab sp<CR>:e ~/.vim/snippets/php.snippets<CR>
map <C-F10> :tab sp<CR>:e sudo /etc/hosts<CR>
map <C-F9> :tab sp<CR>:e ~/Code/AdminLTE-2.3.0/pages/UI/icons.html<CR>
```